# Game with number theory

Tags: modular-arithmetic, contest-math, arithmetic

Let $k$, $n$ be fixed positive integers. In a circular table, there are placed pins numbered successively with the numbers $1, 2 \dots, n$, with $1$ and $n$ neighbors. It is known that pin $1$ is golden and the others are white. Arnaldo and Bernaldo play a game, in which a ring is placed initially on one of the pins and at each step it changes position. The game begins with Bernaldo choosing a starting pin for the ring, and the first step consists of the following: Arnaldo chooses a positive integer $d$ any and Bernaldo moves the ring $d$ pins clockwise or counterclockwise (positions are considered modulo $n$, i.e., pins $x$, $y$ equal if and only if $n$ divides $x-y$). After that, the ring changes its position according to one of the following rules, to be chosen at every step by Arnaldo:

Rule 1: Arnaldo chooses a positive integer $d$ and Bernaldo moves the ring $d$ pins clockwise or counterclockwise.

Rule 2: Arnaldo chooses a direction (clockwise or counterclockwise), and Bernaldo moves the ring in the chosen direction in $d$ or $kd$ pins, where $d$ is the size of the last displacement performed.

Arnaldo wins if, after a finite number of steps, the ring is moved to the golden pin. Determine, as a function of $k$, the values of $n$ for which Arnaldo has a strategy that guarantees his victory, no matter how Bernaldo plays.

I had thought of this motto: Lemma: If $A$ can win with $n=n'$, then so can $A$ win with $n=2n'$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan $k$ is referenced in the first sentence, it's just hard to spot.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Thanks for pointing this out. I missed that initial reference to $k$.